# jQuery's getScript and the local file system-- limitations/alternatives?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I'm working on a help-system which is based on a local file system.  It is intended to be shipped with a product which is not used on internet-enabled machines, so it must be a stand alone webpage, without any dependencies on a web server.

This introduces a few challenges.  Namely, the directory structure that the files exist in require navigating "up and over" to access some .js files which are required to display the help system.  This use to be implemented using the jQuery getScript function, but I have ran into some problems using this on the local file system.

At first glance, it seemed that if my webpage was being served out of the C:/dev/webpage/html/ directory, and the files I needed were in C:/dev/webpage/js/(topic)/file.js, I could just build an absolute path (file:///...) and pass that into the getScript function.

However, after testing this, it does not seem that the getScript function will let me go up a level from the html directory (where the html file is located which has the main code for the webpage).  Unfortunately, I can not change the directory structure, nor can I change the .js file structure/format.

Is there an alternative for loading/executing javascript files that are in a file structure where I need to go "up and over"?

Thanks,

Edit-  I did look at this question that resembled mine, but the recommendation of changing data to a JSON format was not an option in my case: [Permission Denied using Javascript/jQuery on a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852265/permission-denied-using-javascript-jquery-on-a-local-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that it won't let you go up a level...which is also true in some cases, it's that you're probably hitting the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in place for security.  Here's a few solutions/options you have.

### Option 1

Your best long-term option for this is to setup a web server on the box, edit/save the file as you have it, but view it through a `http://localhost` url.  This is going to be the easiest way to get what you want if you're doing a lot of HTML/CSS/JS work down the road.

### Option 2

Alternatively, you could load you page in chrome (maybe other browsers) and *disable* that policy so you can get some work done (create a different shortcut for development, not general use!).

For [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) you disable it by editing the shortcut and adding `--disable-web-security` to your command line, for example:

```
C:\Users\USERHERE\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

Comment: Thanks, it did indeed turn out to be this limitation.

Comment: According to the jQuery site, the issue is in IE 11's handling of the ActiveX requests: https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14475

Answer (score -1):

Why not just build a relative path?  An absolute path is a bad idea anyway, since you can't be 100% sure of the installation path. (Some clients may install to D: for example.)

If the page is "file://something/html/thepage.html", does "../js/script.js" work?

Comment: I've found relative paths on the `file:` scheme/protocol to be full of cross-browser inconsistencies that jQuery at least does not smooth over.