# ng-include in angularjs throws error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head> 
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angularmy.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular.css"/>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myMod" ng-controller="myCont">
        <div ng-include="'angular3.html'">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

All the files are in the same folder, even angular3.html but when I try to run it gives me this error :

> Error: NETWORK_ERR ([arguments not
>   available])@file://localhost/C:/Users/amondapr/Desktop/html/angularjs/ng-include/angular.js:12014
>   sendReq([arguments not
>   available])@file://localhost/C:/Users/amondapr/Desktop/html/angularjs/ng-include/angular.js:11776
>   serverRequest([arguments not
>   available])@file://localhost/C:/Users/amondapr/Desktop/html/angularjs/ng-include/angular.js:11571
>   processQueue([arguments not
>   available])@file://localhost/C:/Users/amondapr/Desktop/html/angularjs/ng-include/angular.js:16383
>   ([arguments not
>   available])@file://localhost/C:/Users/amondapr/Desktop/html/angularjs/ng-include/angular.js:16399
>   ([arguments not
>   available])@file://localhost/C:/Users/amondapr/Desktop/html/angularjs/ng-include/angular.js:17682
>   ([arguments not
>   available])@file://localhost/C:/Users/amondapr/Desktop/html/angularjs/ng-include/angular.js:17495
>   ([arguments not
>   available])@file://localhost/C:/Users/amondapr/Desktop/html/angularjs/ng-include/angular.js:17790
>   bootstrapApply([arguments not
>   available])@file://localhost/C:/Users/amondapr/Desktop/html/angularjs/ng-include/angular.js:1761
>   invoke([arguments not
>   available])@file://localhost/C:/Users/amondapr/Desktop/html/angularjs/ng-include/angular.js:4718

Has anyone else faced this problem , if yes then how to correct it ?

Comment: I think you need to put your angular app on a webserver (like wampserver, or a vagrant box)

Comment: But why??? The tutorials that i am following have their html file in the same directory

Comment: yes, but the whole directory is served through a http server.

Comment: Take a look at that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2886389/1218980)

Comment: You won't be able to load the `angular3.html` template file if you don't use a web server. What you can do to test this without a server is to use an inline-template `<script type="text/ng-template" id="angular3.html">` [more details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124767/using-inline-templates-in-angular)

Answer (score 2):

You have to run a local http server.

Easiest way is using `python -m http.server` (with Python 3) running in application folder. 
Then you can just access `http://localhost:8000`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac you can use [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/)